# Что с вордпрессом: не центрирует описание под картинками

Tags: wordpress, вёрстка

Один и тот же подрядчик перенес нам 2 сайта с Тильды на Вордпресс.

На одном сайте во всех статьях под картинками описание центрируется, во втором - нет. При этом:

- в редакторе отображает по центру, а на деле при сохранении - не по центру.
  [image: вид с редактора]

[image: после сохранения]

- копирую стиль блока с сайта А и переношу на блок сайта Б - тот же результат: показывает что по центру, при сохранении - нет.
- пробовала другие блоки с графикой - ну не очень смотрится, отпадает.
- *из разряда магии*: подумала, что мой комп заговорен, попросила коллегу провести манипуляции со своего компа, честно, один раз даже вышло по центру. Но потом все, как только я отредачила статью - по центру след простыл. И с тех пор и у коллеги не центрируется.

Что делать? Помогите советом, пожалуйста.

Comment: `Что делать?` -- смотреть на стили блока либо обращаться к подрядчику который это делал.

Comment: ссылку на сайт дайте, на конкретную страницу, где не центруется

Comment: @Simon смотреть где? Я просмотрела на обоих сайтах, и копировала настройки и не копировала и делала просто стандартные манипуляции. В редакторе все ок - по центру, только публикуешь - слева описание. К подрядчику да, уже стучимся неделю)

Comment: @humster_spb например, вот на этой странице https://debugmail.io/alternatives-comparisons/debug-mail-vs-google-smtp/

Comment: @Юлия в веб инспекторе браузера

Comment: @Simon спасибо, посмотрю и постараюсь не увидеть "фигу"...)

Comment: @Юлия так а какого ответа Вы здесь ожидали? Это не имеет отношения к настройкам, в данном случае. Там нет стилей для `figcaption` или `figure` которые центрировали бы текст при наличии класса `aligncenter`, потому и не центрируется.

Comment: @Юлия можете попробовать добавить свои стили через кастомайзер: `.wp-block-image .aligncenter > figcaption { text-align: center; }`

Comment: нужно дописать в стилях `.wp-block-image .aligncenter>figcaption {
    text-align: center;
}`

Comment: @Simon я немного пошутила, потому что передам ваш ответ коллеге, которая оперативнее вкурит, чем я. Спасибо за подсказку что делать!

Comment: @humster_spb спасибо большое за подсказку!

Comment: Действительно помогло, спасибо!